# Add a diagonal of zeros to a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Suppose I have a matrix `A` of dimension `Nx(N-1)` in MATLAB, e.g.

```
N=5;
A=[1  2  3  4;
   5  6  7  8;
   9  10 11 12;
   13 14 15 16;
   17 18 19 20 ];
```

I want to transform `A` into an `NxN` matrix `B`, just by adding a zero diagonal, i.e.,

```
B=[ 0  1   2   3   4;
    5  0   6   7   8;
    9  10  0   11  12;
    13 14  15  0   16;
    17 18  19  20  0];
```

---

This code does what I want:

```
B_temp = zeros(N,N); 
B_temp(1,:) = [0 A(1,:)];
B_temp(N,:) = [A(N,:) 0];
for j=2:N-1
    B_temp(j,:)= [A(j,1:j-1) 0 A(j,j:end)];
end
B = B_temp;
```

Could you suggest an efficient way to vectorise it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with upper and lower triangular parts of the matrix (`triu` and `tril`).

Then it's a 1 line solution:

```
B = [tril(A,-1) zeros(N, 1)] + [zeros(N,1) triu(A)];
```

---

**Edit: benchmark**

This is a comparison of the loop method, the 2 methods in [Sardar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47713640/3978545), and my method above.

Benchmark code, using `timeit` for timing and directly lifting code from question and answers:

```
function benchie()
    N = 1e4; A = rand(N,N-1); % Initialise large matrix
    % Set up anonymous functions for input to timeit
    s1 = @() sardar1(A,N); s2 = @() sardar2(A,N); 
    w =  @() wolfie(A,N); u = @() user3285148(A,N);
    % timings
    timeit(s1), timeit(s2), timeit(w), timeit(u)
end
function sardar1(A, N) % using eye as an indexing matrix
    B=double(~eye(N)); B(find(B))=A.'; B=B.';
end
function sardar2(A,N) % similar to sardar1, but avoiding slow operations
    B=1-eye(N); B(logical(B))=A.'; B=B.';
end
function wolfie(A,N) % using triangular parts of the matrix
    B = [tril(A,-1) zeros(N, 1)] + [zeros(N,1) triu(A)];
end
function user3285148(A, N) % original looping method
    B = zeros(N,N); B(1,:) = [0 A(1,:)]; B(N,:) = [A(N,:) 0];
    for j=2:N-1; B(j,:)= [A(j,1:j-1) 0 A(j,j:end)]; end
end
```

Results:

- Sardar method 1: 2.83 secs
- Sardar method 2: 1.82 secs
- My method: 1.45 secs
- Looping method: 3.80 secs (!)

Conclusions:

- Your desire to vectorise this was well founded, looping is way slower than other methods.
- Avoiding data conversions and `find` for large matrices is important, saving ~35% processing time between Sardar's methods.
- By avoiding indexing all together you can save a *further* 20% processing time.

Answer (score 5):

Generate a matrix with zeros at diagonal and ones at non-diagonal indices. Replace the non-diagonal elements with the transpose of `A` (since MATLAB is column major). Transpose again to get the correct order.

```
B = double(~eye(N));  %Converting to double since we want to replace with double entries
B(find(B)) = A.';     %Replacing the entries
B = B.';              %Transposing again to get the matrix in the correct order
```

**Edit:**

As [*suggested*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713435/add-a-zero-diagonal-to-a-matrix-in-matlab#comment82387253_47713640) by [***Wolfie***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3978545/wolfie) for the same algorithm, you can get rid of conversion to `double` and the use of `find` with:

```
B = 1-eye(N);
B(logical(B)) = A.'; 
B = B.';
```

Comment: You could also similarly do `B = 1-eye(N);` to avoid conversion to and from a logical matrix, then `B(logical(B)) = A.'; B = B.';` to avoid using `find`. Not sure which is more efficient.

Comment: @Wolfie Good point, I think getting rid of conversion and `find`, and dealing with logical indices  would be more efficient.  Thanks

Comment: Efficiencies now included in my answer :)

Comment: @Wolfie tbh I wasn't expecting matrix indexing to be slower than `tril` `triu`

Comment: Haha didn't know if you'd seen it! Yeah same, that's why I was curious enough to do a benchie! Not sure what happens inside `triu`/`tril` but they appear to be compiled functions so something pacey happening in the backend and then a simple addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert any vector on a diagonal of a matrix, one can use plain indexing. The following snippet gives you the indices of the desired diagonal, given the size of the square matrix `n` (matrix is `n` by `n`), and the number of the diagonal `k`, where `k=0` corresponds to the main diagonal, positive numbers of `k` to upper diagonals and negative numbers of `k` to lower diagonals. `ixd` finally gives you the 2D indices.

```
function [idx] = diagidx(n,k)
% n size of square matrix
% k number of diagonal
if k==0 % identity
    idx = [(1:n).' (1:n).']; % [row col]
elseif k>0 % Upper diagonal
    idx = [(1:n-k).' (1+k:n).'];
elseif k<0 % lower diagonal
    idx = [(1+abs(k):n).' (1:n-abs(k)).'];
end
end
```

Usage:

```
n=10;
k=3;
A = rand(n);
idx = diagidx(n,k);

A(idx) = 1:(n-k);
```